# Fix for getting "deprecated and will be removed in Swift 4" warning for tableView functions

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, deprecated, swift4

I just upgraded my codes to Swift 4 and now receiving this warning on console for all tableView function.

```
tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:] is deprecated and will be removed in Swift 4; add explicit '@objc' to the declaration to emit the Objective-C entrypoint in Swift 4 and suppress this message

tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] is deprecated and will be removed in Swift 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code for `cellForRow`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
}
```

Use below one to identify cells which are displaying

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}
```

if you have doubt regarding datasource and delegate function select UITableViewDataSource or UITableViewDelegate and right click jump to definition that will lead to get your functions

Hope this will help you